# Trouble making customized DefaultKeyBinding.dict work throughout

Tags: macos, dictionary, emacs, key-bindings

I'm running OS X 10.11.  I've been creating customized key binding by editing my ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict file, and I've successfully got a bunch of emacs-like shortcuts  to work in parts of some applications, but for the most part, my User-specific keybindings have been overridden by app-specific shortcuts.

For example, Command-a in Mail moves to the beginning of the line.  But Command-a in textedit or notes doesn't move to the beginning of the line. Instead, it selects all. Command-*e* moves to the end of the line (as I want it to), I'm guessing because Command-e is not already a predefined app-specific shortcut...

Anybody had experience with this problem? My understanding was that any bindings defined in DefaultKeyBinding.dict were  supposed to supersede app-specific bindings...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nope, afaik app specific shortcuts supersede global ones. Also, personally I think it's better to use `ctrl+KEY` for navigation and remap the existing ones. See [OS X Human Interface Guidelines for Keyboard Shortcuts](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/Keyboard.html) and the [official os x shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236).